# How to know if an order is paid ? When "state" is "processing"?

Tags: orders, payment, ce-1.6.2.0, state

I'm running Magento 1.6.2.

I need to determine if an order is paid. If yes, I generate some XML data for export.
There is many cases in the Magento order/payment/shipment workflow.

My first guess is when the attribute "state" of the order is defined as "processing", but I'm not sure because of the large amount of possibilities in this workflow. May be this case is not covering all the possibilities ...

Am I right with that ?

Comment: Check if there is an invoice generated for the order.

Comment: Just invoice ? No other stuff ? I'm surprised, it seems too easy to be real aha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Usually the presence of an invoice means it's been paid.

Comment: That's not enough in all cases, as an invoice can be unpaid. And it's possible that an invoice doesn't cover all ordered items, so there may be more than one invoice.

Comment: Checking the state may do depending on your workflow, but the state "processing" may also mean that the order is sent, but not paid yet. I wouldn't use that.

Comment: Hi Marius !! If customer has paid when the test mode is on in authorize.net and the order is in "Processing" state. Does the payment can be retrieved after turning the test mode Off.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call `$order->getBaseTotalDue()`. If this is 0, the order is fully paid.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, this answer seems to be the one who fit the most to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See Andreas answer on how to determine if there is anything left to pay. To answer your other question - using state == processing is not good enough. A quick test to show this is to ship an unpaid order - this will also move an order to the processing state even though the order is still unpaid.